# How to access inner class in java (android)?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a mobile app and in my MainActivity class in android studio and I'm trying to call a method that is within an inner fragment class.  Within this fragment class I have another class called WebViewInterface:

```
public class tab2_upgrade extends Fragment {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_upgrade, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/tab2.html");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(getActivity()), "Android");

        return view;
    }

    public class WebViewInterface {

        WebViewInterface(Context myWebViewFragment) {
            context = myWebViewFragment;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

But when I try to access this inner class to call a method within it from my MainActivity I get an error as if it does not recognize it (but can find it):

```
@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    tab2_upgrade tab2 = new tab2_upgrade();
    tab2.WebViewInterface tab2WebView = new tab2.WebViewInterface();
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    tab2_upgrade tab2 = new tab2_upgrade();
    tab2.WebViewInterface tab2WebView = tab2.new WebViewInterface();
}
```

Could someone please tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix this so that I can access the WebViewInterface class in my fragment class??  Please see the attached images to see the errors in red.  Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have a no-argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `WebViewInterface` constructor takes a `Context` argument, but you're trying to call it without any argument.

BTW, `tab2_upgrade` and `WebViewInterface` are very confusing names for classes.  See the official guide to [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: How do I get the proper kind of context to pass into it?  My myWebViewFragment context from my MainActivity class??

Comment: @Tanya Why pass in a context at all instead of having the `Fragment` call `getActivity()` when it needs a context?  I would say you need to rethink everything, but I'm trying to focus on your specific question.

Comment: I added it for my javascript interface:
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(getActivity()), "Android");

Comment: Ok I took the constructor away from my WebViewInterface class but I still have the same error in my MainActivity class